# TFS 2015 XAML Build Failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I migrated a collection from TFS 2012.2 to a new TFS 2015, I configured XAML build agent for that collection, when I tried to run the build, it failed during "Associate Changesets and Work Items" activity.

From the stack trace, I can see it couldn't change the work items, I tried to reproduce the case with a small project with the same everything but it worked fine?!

**The build log**:

> Exception Stack Trace: at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String
>   requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result,
>   MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp,
>   IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement
>   package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SaveWorkItems(WorkItem[]
>   workitems, Boolean bulk, SaveFlags saveFlags)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.BatchSaveHelper.TryUpdate(WorkItemStore
>   store, WorkItem[] workitems, SaveFlags saveFlags, List`1 errors)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.BatchSaveHelper.TryUpdate(WorkItemStore
>   store, WorkItem[] workitems, SaveFlags saveFlags, List`1 errors)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.BatchSaveHelper.BatchSave(WorkItemStore
>   store, WorkItem[] workitems, SaveFlags saveFlags)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WitBatchSaveWorkItems.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)
>
> at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>
> at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

**Event Log:**

> Default Controller - tfsbuild: Cancelled the workflow instance for
>   build vstfs:///Build/Build/430 with ID
>   {2da10eef-3c75-48ce-852b-78436a594f85}. Exception
>   Type:System.NullReferenceException Exception Message:Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. Stack Trace:   at
>   System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: are you using TFS 2012 controller to build?

Answer (score 0):

This is **NOT** a solution but a workaround:

In your build definition you can disable the setting:
"Associate Changesets and Work Items" by setting it to false. This should make the checkin work.
It is found under ->Process->Advanced->Associate Changesets and Work Items.
[image]
This is a valid solution in my case because I don't need the associations but it might not always be OK to leave the associations out.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

```
1.)Stop the Build Service on the Build Machine
2.)Delete the folders inside the below path in build machine – C:\Users\
    [BUILDSERVICEACCOUNT]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\5.0
3.)Start the Build Service on the Build Machine
```